# Unable to run android.bat file. xcopy command halts the execution

Tags: javascript, android, windows, batch-file, nativescript

I'm new to Android development on windows and don't have any idea about `android.bat` file.
I just wanted to use for developing apps with **NativeScript** so i have installed android-sdk and did all the stuff of system variables.

Firstly statically defined path for `java_exe`

> set java_exe=%JAVA_HOME%bin\java.exe

and for `javaw_exe`

> set javaw_exe=%JAVA_HOME%bin\javaw.exe

in `find_java.bat` file.

These errors i got when i first ran `android` command on `cmd`.

> 1. Unable to find SWT.jar

```
> Changed to directly `lib\x86_64\swt.jar`
```

> 2. `XCOPY` for copying from tool to temp directory ( i guess!?)

```
> Now waiting for lifetime to complete...
```

> Pressing CTRL+C stops the execution
>
> results in ' System cannot find the path specified' 21 times

What to do now. Googled it but no solutions....

Here goes my android.bat:

```
@echo off
rem Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project
rem
rem Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
rem you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
rem You may obtain a copy of the License at
rem
rem      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
rem
rem Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
rem distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
rem WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
rem See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
rem limitations under the License.

rem Useful links:
rem Command-line reference:
rem   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx

rem don't modify the caller's environment
setlocal enableextensions

rem Set up prog to be the path of this script, including following symlinks,
rem and set up progdir to be the fully-qualified pathname of its directory.
set prog=%~f0

rem Grab current directory before we change it
set work_dir=%cd%

rem Change current directory and drive to where the script is, to avoid
rem issues with directories containing whitespaces.
cd /d %~dp0


rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe=
call lib\find_java.bat
rem if not defined java_exe goto :EOF

set jar_path=lib\sdkmanager.jar;lib\swtmenubar.jar

rem Set SWT.Jar path based on current architecture (x86 or x86_64)
rem for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%java_exe%" -jar lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a
rem     for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%java_exe%" -jar %~dp0lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a
set swt_path=%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\lib\x86_64\swt.jar
:MkTempCopy
rem Copy android.bat and its required libs to a temp dir.
rem This avoids locking the tool dir in case the user is trying to update it.

set tmp_dir=%TEMP%\temp-android-tool

xcopy "%swt_path%" "%tmp_dir%\lib\x86_64\swt.jar" /I /E /C /G /R /Y /Q > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\common.jar         "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\commons-codec*     "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\commons-compress*  "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\commons-logging*   "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\dvlib.jar          "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\gson*              "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\guava*             "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\httpclient*        "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\httpcore*          "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\httpmime*          "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\layoutlib-api.jar  "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\org-eclipse-*      "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\sdk*               "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\swtmenubar.jar     "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul

rem jar_path and swt_path are relative to PWD so we don't need to adjust them, just change dirs.
set tools_dir=%cd%
cd /d "%tmp_dir%"

:EndTempCopy

rem The global ANDROID_SWT always override the SWT.Jar path
if defined ANDROID_SWT set swt_path=%ANDROID_SWT%

if exist "%swt_path%" goto SetPath
    echo ERROR: SWT folder '%swt_path%' does not exist.
    echo Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
goto :EOF

:SetPath
rem Finally exec the java program and end here.
REM set REMOTE_DEBUG=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
call "%java_exe% %REMOTE_DEBUG%" "-Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir=%tools_dir%" "-Dcom.android.sdkmanager.workdir=%work_dir%" -classpath "%jar_path%;%swt_path%\swt.jar" com.android.sdkmanager.Main %*

rem EOF
```

Comment: Please include the actual code of the batch file. Otherwise all we can give you are very wild guesses.

Comment: Where did you get this .bat file? Are you setting up NativeScript on your machine and getting these errors using the batch file?

Comment: This is actually the Android SDK/tools/android.bat file

Comment: @BradMartin  updated the question checkout!

Comment: @VladimirEnchev yes its the problem of android.bat file.

Comment: A couple diagnostic things: 
Can you verify that *echo %TEMP%* gives you a valid path?
Can you verfiy that *echo %ANDROID_HOME%* give you a valid path to the main root path of the android sdk folder?
Can you verify that *echo %JAVA_HOME%* gives you a valid path to Java?

On my machine: 
`TEMP=C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp`
`JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21`
`ANDROID_HOME=C:\Progra~2\Android\sdk`

Comment: @Nathanael yes my paths are similar! Don't have any idea for `swt_path` .
`echo %ANDROID_HOME%, %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk , C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92`

Comment: You might try changing the %ANDROID_HOME% and %JAVA_HOME% to the short name, some times the apps don't like spaces in names.   Try:
*dir C:\progra~1\android* or *dir c:\progra~2\android* and see which one of those actually resolves to your program files (x86).   Then use that as the path part instead of *c:\program files (x86)*

Comment: @Nathanael did like what you have said. But still the command `xcopy` hangs the execution.

Comment: So xcopy actually "hangs" and you have to kill the process?  Can you verify that *echo %TEMP%* actually echos a value and that the folder it references actually exists and that you can easily copy a file from the SDK folder to the %TEMP% folder it might be a permissions issue on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the android sdk for windows and comparing your version of the android.bat located in the tools directory your version seems a bit off trying using the version below once it works try updating the sdk.

```
@echo off
rem Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project
rem
rem Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
rem you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
rem You may obtain a copy of the License at
rem
rem      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
rem
rem Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
rem distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
rem WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
rem See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
rem limitations under the License.

rem Useful links:
rem Command-line reference:
rem   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx

rem don't modify the caller's environment
setlocal enableextensions

rem Set up prog to be the path of this script, including following symlinks,
rem and set up progdir to be the fully-qualified pathname of its directory.
set prog=%~f0

rem Grab current directory before we change it
set work_dir=%cd%

rem Change current directory and drive to where the script is, to avoid
rem issues with directories containing whitespaces.
cd /d %~dp0


rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe=
call lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF

set jar_path=lib\sdkmanager.jar;lib\swtmenubar.jar

rem Set SWT.Jar path based on current architecture (x86 or x86_64)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%java_exe%" -jar lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a

:MkTempCopy
    rem Copy android.bat and its required libs to a temp dir.
    rem This avoids locking the tool dir in case the user is trying to update it.

    set tmp_dir=%TEMP%\temp-android-tool
    xcopy "%swt_path%" "%tmp_dir%\%swt_path%" /I /E /C /G /R /Y /Q > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\common.jar         "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\commons-codec*     "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\commons-compress*  "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\commons-logging*   "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\dvlib.jar          "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\gson*              "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\guava*             "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\httpclient*        "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\httpcore*          "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\httpmime*          "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\layoutlib-api.jar  "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\org-eclipse-*      "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\sdk*               "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\swtmenubar.jar     "%tmp_dir%\lib\"          > nul

    rem jar_path and swt_path are relative to PWD so we don't need to adjust them, just change dirs.
    set tools_dir=%cd%
    cd /d "%tmp_dir%"

:EndTempCopy

rem The global ANDROID_SWT always override the SWT.Jar path
if defined ANDROID_SWT set swt_path=%ANDROID_SWT%

if exist "%swt_path%" goto SetPath
    echo ERROR: SWT folder '%swt_path%' does not exist.
    echo Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
    goto :EOF

:SetPath
rem Finally exec the java program and end here.
REM set REMOTE_DEBUG=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
call "%java_exe% %REMOTE_DEBUG%" "-Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir=%tools_dir%" "-Dcom.android.sdkmanager.workdir=%work_dir%" -classpath "%jar_path%;%swt_path%\swt.jar" com.android.sdkmanager.Main %*

rem EOF
```